# Xamarin Slider OnDraw is called only once

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am inheriting from `Xamarin..Android.SliderRenderer` to create a circular slider. I created a View class and assembled them already:

```
[assembly: ExportRendererAttribute(typeof(CircleSliderView), typeof(CircleSliderViewRenderer))]

public class CircleSliderViewRenderer : SliderRenderer
```

I carefully avoid the SetWillNotDraw trap in constructor:

```
this.SetWillNotDraw(false);
```

Finally, override the OnDraw method to draw something else than the original one:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    ...

    DrawTrack(canvas, view.MaximumTrackColor.ToAndroid(), maxSweep);
    DrawTrack(canvas, view.MinimumTrackColor.ToAndroid(), minSweep);

    // no call to super.OnDraw()
}
```

As a result, I have an arc drawn:

[image]

However, I have 2 issues here:

- Old slider drawing is still there.
- My OnDraw is called once and never again (even after value change).

Apparently, there is another method than OnDraw that is being called continually (susceptibly when the value changes). But the API docs do not help at all on finding this method. Does anyone know which methods I should override to solve above issues?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could custom a circle slider which Inherited the View,then use ViewRenderer instead of SliderRenderer.

Custom **CircularSlider** in Android Project:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Java.Lang;
using Math = Java.Lang.Math;

namespace EntryCa.Droid
{
  public class CircularSlider : View, INotifyPropertyChanged
  { 
    int _arcRadius;
    float _progressSweep;
    RectF _arcRect = new RectF();
    Paint _arcPaint;
    Paint _progressPaint;
    int _translateX;
    int _translateY;
    int _thumbXPos;
    int _thumbYPos;
    float _touchInsideIgnoreRadius;
    float _touchOutsideIgnoreRadius;

    int _touchCorrection = 40;
    /// <summary>
    /// This indicates how many points a touch event can go inside or outside the circle before the slider stops updating.
    /// This may never exceed half of the controls size (this can create unwanted behaviour).
    /// The value must be greater or equal to 0.
    /// </summary>
    public int TouchCorrection
    {
        get
        {
            return _touchCorrection;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_touchCorrection < 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(TouchCorrection), "The value must be at least 0");

            _touchCorrection = value;

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    int _sweepAngle = 180;
    /// <summary>
    /// This indicates how many degrees the circle is used.
    /// The value must be between 0 and 360
    /// </summary>
    public int SweepAngle
    {
        get { return _sweepAngle; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 360)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(SweepAngle), "The value must be between 0 and 360");

            _sweepAngle = value;

            if (Width > 0 && Height > 0)
            {
                CalculateArcRect(Width, Height);
                UpdateProgress();
            }

            Invalidate();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    int _startAngle = 180;
    /// <summary>
    /// This indicates at how many degrees in the circle the indicator will start.
    /// The value must be between 0 and 360.
    /// </summary>
    public int StartAngle
    {
        get { return _startAngle; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 360)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(StartAngle), "The value must be between 0 and 360");

            _startAngle = value;

            if (Width > 0 && Height > 0)
            {
                CalculateArcRect(Width, Height);
                UpdateProgress();
            }

            Invalidate();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The color of the uncompleted progress indicator.
    /// </summary>
    public Color Color
    {
        get
        {
            return _arcPaint.Color;
        }
        set
        {
            _arcPaint.Color = value;
            Invalidate();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The color of the completed progress indicator.
    /// </summary>
    public Color ProgressColor
    {
        get
        {
            return _progressPaint.Color;
        }
        set
        {
            _progressPaint.Color = value;
            Invalidate();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    Bitmap _thumb;
    /// <summary>
    /// The thumb image to indicate the current progress.
    /// The bitmap must have the same width and height.
    /// </summary>
    public Bitmap Thumb
    {
        get
        {
            return _thumb;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value.Width != value.Height)
                throw new ArgumentException("The image must be a square (same width and height)", nameof(Thumb));

            _thumb = value;

            if (Width > 0 && Height > 0)
            {
                CalculateArcRect(Width, Height);
                UpdateProgress();
            }

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The line width in pixels of the circle.
    /// </summary>
    public int LineWidth
    {
        get
        {
            return (int)_arcPaint.StrokeWidth;
        }
        set
        {
            _arcPaint.StrokeWidth = value;
            _progressPaint.StrokeWidth = value;

            if (Width > 0 && Height > 0)
            {
                CalculateArcRect(Width, Height);
                UpdateThumbPosition();
            }

            Invalidate();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This indicates if the circle line has rounded corners at the end of the line.
    /// </summary>
    public bool RoundEdges
    {
        get
        {
            return _arcPaint.StrokeCap == Paint.Cap.Round;
        }
        set
        {
            _arcPaint.StrokeCap = value ? Paint.Cap.Round : Paint.Cap.Square;
            _progressPaint.StrokeCap = value ? Paint.Cap.Round : Paint.Cap.Square;

            Invalidate();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    int _maximum;
    /// <summary>
    /// The maximum value of the progress.
    /// </summary>
    public int Maximum
    {
        get
        {
            return _maximum;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Maximum can not be less than 0");

            if (value < Progress)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Maximum can not be less than Progress value" + Progress);

            if (value != _maximum)
            {
                _maximum = value;

                UpdateProgress();
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    int _progress;
    /// <summary>
    /// The current progress.
    /// </summary>
    public int Progress
    {
        get
        {
            return _progress;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Progress can not be less than 0");

            if (value > Maximum)
                throw new IllegalStateException("Progress can not be more than Maximum value " + Maximum);

            if (value != _progress)
            {
                _progress = value;

                UpdateProgress();

                ProgressChanged?.Invoke(this, value);

                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    bool _clockwise = true;
    /// <summary>
    /// This indicates if the slider should work clockwise or counter clockwise.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Clockwise
    {
        get
        {
            return _clockwise;
        }
        set
        {
            _clockwise = value;
            Invalidate();
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This indicates if the user can interact with the control or not
    /// </summary>
    public override bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Enabled;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Enabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when one of the custom properties is changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Triggered when the progress value has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<int> ProgressChanged;

    public CircularSlider(Context context)
        : base(context)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public CircularSlider(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public CircularSlider(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
        : base(context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Init();
    }

    void Init()
    {
        _arcPaint = new Paint
        {
            AntiAlias = true,
            StrokeCap = Paint.Cap.Round
        };
        _arcPaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);

        _progressPaint = new Paint
        {
            AntiAlias = true,
            StrokeCap = Paint.Cap.Round
        };
        _progressPaint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);

        LineWidth = (int)(4 * Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);

        UpdateProgress();
    }

    protected override void OnMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        base.OnMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        var width = GetDefaultSize(SuggestedMinimumWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
        var height = GetDefaultSize(SuggestedMinimumHeight, heightMeasureSpec);

        CalculateArcRect(width, height);

        UpdateThumbPosition();

        // Don't use the exact radius but include TouchCorrection or else this makes interaction too tricky
        if (Thumb != null)
        {
            _touchInsideIgnoreRadius = _arcRadius - (Math.Min(Thumb.Width, Thumb.Height) + TouchCorrection);
            _touchOutsideIgnoreRadius = _arcRadius + (Math.Min(Thumb.Width, Thumb.Height) + TouchCorrection);
        }
        else
        {
            _touchInsideIgnoreRadius = _arcRadius - TouchCorrection;
            _touchOutsideIgnoreRadius = _arcRadius + TouchCorrection;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.OnDraw(canvas);

        if (!Clockwise)
            canvas.Scale(-1, 1, _arcRect.CenterX(), _arcRect.CenterY());

        canvas.DrawArc(_arcRect, StartAngle, SweepAngle, false, _arcPaint);
        canvas.DrawArc(_arcRect, StartAngle, _progressSweep, false, _progressPaint);

        if (Thumb != null)
        {
            var left = (_translateX - _thumbXPos) - (Thumb.Width / 2);
            var top = (_translateY - _thumbYPos) - (Thumb.Height / 2);

            canvas.DrawBitmap(Thumb, left, top, null);
        }
    }

    void CalculateArcRect(int width, int height)
    {
        _translateX = (int)(width * 0.5f);
        _translateY = (int)(height * 0.5f);

        var min = Math.Min(width, height);

        if (Thumb != null)
        {
            var arcDiameter = min - (LineWidth + Thumb.Width);
            _arcRadius = arcDiameter / 2;

            var top = height / 2 - (arcDiameter / 2);
            var left = width / 2 - (arcDiameter / 2);

            _arcRect.Set(left, top, left + arcDiameter, top + arcDiameter);
        }
        else
        {
            var arcDiameter = min - LineWidth;
            _arcRadius = arcDiameter / 2;

            var top = height / 2 - (arcDiameter / 2);
            var left = width / 2 - (arcDiameter / 2);

            _arcRect.Set(left, top, left + arcDiameter, top + arcDiameter);
        }
    }

    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (Enabled)
        {
            Parent?.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

            switch (e.Action)
            {
                case MotionEventActions.Down:
                case MotionEventActions.Move:
                    UpdateOnTouch(e);
                    break;
                case MotionEventActions.Up:
                case MotionEventActions.Cancel:
                    Pressed = false;
                    Parent?.RequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    void UpdateOnTouch(MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (IgnoreTouch(e.GetX(), e.GetY()))
            return;

        Pressed = true;

        var touchAngle = GetTouchDegrees(e.GetX(), e.GetY());

        var progress = GetProgressForAngle(touchAngle);

        if (progress >= 0)
        {
            Progress = progress;
        }
    }

    bool IgnoreTouch(float xPos, float yPos)
    {
        var x = xPos - _translateX;
        var y = yPos - _translateY;

        return PointIsInsideCircle(_touchInsideIgnoreRadius, x, y) || !PointIsInsideCircle(_touchOutsideIgnoreRadius, x, y);
    }

    bool PointIsInsideCircle(double circleRadius, double x, double y)
    {
        return (Math.Pow(x, 2) + Math.Pow(y, 2)) < (Math.Pow(circleRadius, 2));
    }

    double GetTouchDegrees(float xPos, float yPos)
    {
        float x = xPos - _translateX;
        float y = yPos - _translateY;

        if (!Clockwise)
            x = -x;

        // Convert to arc Angle
        var angle = Math.ToDegrees(Math.Atan2(y, x) + (Math.Pi / 2));

        angle -= 90;

        if (angle < 0)
        {
            angle = 360 + angle;
        }

        angle -= StartAngle;

        return angle;
    }

    int GetProgressForAngle(double angle)
    {
        var valuePerDegree = (float)Maximum / SweepAngle;

        var progress = (int)Math.Round(valuePerDegree * angle);

        if (progress < 0 || progress > Maximum)
            return -1;

        return progress;
    }

    void UpdateProgress()
    {
        _progressSweep = (float)Progress / Maximum * SweepAngle;

        UpdateThumbPosition();

        Invalidate();
    }

    void UpdateThumbPosition()
    {
        var thumbAngle = StartAngle + _progressSweep + 180;
        _thumbXPos = (int)(_arcRadius * Math.Cos(Math.ToRadians(thumbAngle)));
        _thumbYPos = (int)(_arcRadius * Math.Sin(Math.ToRadians(thumbAngle)));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the thumb resource identifier.
    /// This will automatically be converted to a bitmap and set to the Thumb property.
    /// </summary>
    public void SetThumbResourceId(int resId)
    {
        Thumb = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, resId);
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
  }
}
```

the in your **CircleSliderViewRenderer** :

```
class CircleSliderViewRenderer: ViewRenderer
{
    Context mContext;
    CircularSlider _slider;
    public CircleSliderViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) 
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
         _slider = new CircularSlider(mContext);
        _slider.Color = Android.Graphics.Color.Red;
        _slider.ProgressColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Yellow;
        _slider.Maximum = 50;
        _slider.Progress = 20;
        _slider.ProgressChanged += _slider_ProgressChanged;
        SetNativeControl(_slider);
    }

    private void _slider_ProgressChanged(object sender, int e)
    {
        //when the progress change,you could do something here
    }
  
}
```

the effect like this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe that's a better approach. What do you think about inheriting the view from Slider, but view renderer from ViewRenderer (instead of SliderRenderer)? So I would ensure that they have the same interface. 
Special thanks for providing the code!